# Gitlab CI. Remote: You are not allowed to upload code

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-runner

Авторизация в репозиториях по ssh-key.
пытаюсь в конце пайплайна (раннер на другом серваке) проставить тег на текущий коммит с версией пакета.
Но тег не ставится, а при попытке сделать push, выдает:

```
fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@git.myrepo.org/group/repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Предполагаю что здесь нужны какие-то пляски с ключами на серваке с раннером, но какие, понять не могу.
Ключ для пользователя gitlab-runner на удаленном хосте сгенерил и применил. но он не отображается в списке ключей Deploy Keys. Прдеположу так же, что это потому как раннер уже зареган и ему ключ не требуется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решено!
Реализовал через техническую учетку, добавил ей роль maintainer, завел ее креды как variable и замаскировал их.
на выходе получился такой код

```
- git remote set-url origin "http://$CI_USER:$CI_PASSWD@]@git.myrepo.org/group/$CI_PROJECT_NAME.git"
...
- git tag $TAG_FULL
- git push origin $TAG_FULL
```

подмена адреса обязательна!